# Retrieving data from inner join using LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: postgresql, join, jdbc

These are my two tables:
**table1**

```
qid[PK]     |gid[PK]  |abcd     | xyz  |    date
---------------+---------+---------+------+------------
 00001      |     qwe |      54 |    a | 1994-11-29
 00002      |     asd |       0 |    s | 1994-11-29
 00003      |     azx |      50 | 0.25 | 1994-11-27
```

**table2**

```
qid[PK]     | gid[PK] | user[PK]
------------+---------+--------
 00001      |     qwe | shreya
 00001      |     qwe | nagma
 00001      |     qwe | koena
 00001      |     qwe | paoli
 00002      |     asd | anushka
 00002      |     asd | angelina
 00003      |     azx | jolie
 00003      |     azx | scarlett
 00003      |     azx | sharon
 00003      |     azx | jeniffer
```

As you can see for each `qid and gid` of **table1** there can be any number of rows in **table2**.

**My requirement :**
I want to retrieve all the users for the first 10 values of `qid and gid` from the offset.

**My Query :**

```
    select  * from table1 q inner join table2 a on q.qid=a.qid
 and q.gid=a.gid  order by q.date desc limit 10 offset ?
```

But this query will retrieve  10 rows from offset from the inner join, But I want all rows from table 2 for the 10 rows[offset] from table1.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a subquery (as displayed) or a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) for that purpose:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT qid, gid
   FROM   table1
   ORDER  BY date DESC
   LIMIT  10
   OFFSET ?
   ) q
JOIN   table2 a USING (qid, gid);
```

[`USING (qid, gid)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) is just a shortcut for `ON q.qid = a.qid AND q.gid = a.gid` with the side effect that the two columns are only included *once* in the result.

Comment: Is join same as inner join?

Comment: @Ashwin: Yes, the keyword `INNER` is redundant noise.